# How to print Datagridview has a table in VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, printing, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with information retrieved from a database and i would like the print output to be in table format with lines and columns. My actual methode is simple but the output is very confusing. Any thoughts?

```
  Private Sub Imprimir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Imprimir.Click
    PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1.0
    PrintPreviewDialog1.FindForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
  End Sub

  Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
      System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
      Dim y As Integer = 70
      PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
      e.Graphics.DrawString("TransporGest - Registo de Operações", 
          New Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 30, 30)
      For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dg.Rows
        e.Graphics.DrawString(dr.Cells(0).Value & " | " & dr.Cells(2).Value & 
             " | " & dr.Cells(3).Value & " | " & dr.Cells(4).Value & " | " &
             dr.Cells(6).Value & " | " & dr.Cells(7).Value & " | " & 
             dr.Cells(9).Value & " | " & dr.Cells(11).Value & " | " & 
             dr.Cells(12).Value, New Font("Verdana", 10), Brushes.Black, 30, y)
        y += 20
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You could print how ooopsoft did, but in my opinion reportviewer is a lot easier choice when it comes to datagridview printing, but again it's just my opinion.

Comment: Thank, i'm looking into that option and it looks much easy!

Comment: I have recently worked with reportviewer a lot, so let me know if you have any more questions :)

Comment: I've donne my report with crystal! Was super easy! However, i need in some forms to use my sql query. Is there any way i can change the crystal report query on the VB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add to Form(Design)  `Button1`, `PrintDocument1` ,`PrintPreviewDialog1` , your -> `DataGridView1`

and paste the code:

```
Dim mRow As Integer = 0
Dim newpage As Boolean = True
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    With DataGridView1
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
        Do While mRow < .RowCount
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim h As Single = 0
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                If (newpage) Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                End If
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            newpage = False
            y += h
            mRow += 1
            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                mRow -= 1
                newpage = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        mRow = 0
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! YOU HAVE NO IDEA OF HOW MUCH YOU'VE HELPED ME!

Comment: however, i still have one doubt, how do i select specific rows to print instead of printing them all?

Comment: The code above successfully print a whole datagridview, for one row quickly but not so elegant you can:
a) comment the line `Do While mRow < .RowCount` 
b) comment the line `loop`
c) set for row (4) for example: `Dim mRow As Integer = 4`
d) set  `Dim newpage As Boolean = False`

Comment: I'm sorry, i made a mistake. I meant Columns, not rows. All the Columns wont fit the page even if it's in landscape.

Comment: Note that this has **several issues**, mainly a) on each new page it skips the first row b) if you close the dialog and go back, it will not treat the first page correctly c) it will print invisible columns. There have been several posts how to fix these issues; these and some other issues are resolved in **[How to print datagridview table with its header](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41022394/1070452)**

Answer (score 4):

For pecific Columns (example column 1,3,4)

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim custCells As Integer() = {1, 3, 4}
    With DataGridView1
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
        Do While mRow < .RowCount
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim h As Single = 0
            For Each cell As Integer In custCells
                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, row.Cells(cell).Size.Width, row.Cells(cell).Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                If (newpage) Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(row.Cells(cell).RowIndex).Cells(cell).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                End If
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            newpage = False
            y += h
            mRow += 1
            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                mRow -= 1
                newpage = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        mRow = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find that moving the data to Excel/Word would be as useful:

```
    Private Sub tsbtnCopy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsbtnCopy.Click
    dgv01.SuspendLayout()
    dgv01.RowHeadersVisible = False
    If dgv01.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then dgv01.SelectAll()
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dgv01.GetClipboardContent())
    dgv01.ClearSelection()
    dgv01.RowHeadersVisible = True
    dgv01.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

Or have the user select all (click upper left cell) to copy/Paste.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to fix the disappearing header problem. The thing is that the PrintDocument is called 2 times, once for preview, the second time just before printing. Exactly before printing it is necessary to reset the variables `mRow = 0` and `newpage = True` again.

I used hijacking the print button, which I replaced with my. I added this code to the PRINT button on my form.

```
b.Image = CType(PrintDialog.Controls(1), ToolStrip).ImageList.Images(0)
b.ToolTipText = "Print"
b.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image
AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf PrintPreview_PrintClick
CType(PrintDialog.Controls(1), ToolStrip).Items.RemoveAt(0)
CType(PrintDialog.Controls(1), ToolStrip).Items.Insert(0, b)
```

As a result, the following code is placed in the newly added button

```
Private Sub PrintPreview_PrintClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Try
      mRow = 0
      newpage = True
      PrintDocument.Print()
   Catch ex As Exception
   End Try
End Sub
```