# How to print datagridview table with its header in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, printdocument

I'm creating a print preview function in a system that I'm developing which will preview the datagridview that I want to print. I used ooopsoft's [codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24656705/6842567/) as reference and it works fine except for a slight problem.

Problem:

[image]

In the you can see that the dgv row with serial number 1 is missing. It appears the header has overwritten the 1st row. I have tried a myriad of ways to solve it, but I still can't find the solution. I tried exiting the print preview dialog and opening it again, but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPOEm.png) is the result I got. I think I'm missing a line of code, but I can't figure out what. Please help.

Comment: I suggest you should try using datasets, I assume that you only want to get the output. maybe you could try binding each data from datatable per rows in report table. It will automatically create a header for each plotted data field.

Comment: The bug is in that `For Each cell` loop.  You can see that it prints the header if it is a  `(newpage)` **or** prints the first row data.  You need it to do both; print the header for a new page **and then** print the first row.  Just put the newpage code in its own loop.

Comment: @GNMercado Do you mean using Microsoft Report Viewer? I've already gave it a shot, but I'm getting an exception `cannot convert sql datetime value to system.datetime`.

Comment: It also looks like it will duplicate the last row on each page as the first row on the next page

Comment: @Plutonix I don't think duplicate the last row on each page to the 1st row on the next. In the print preview I have now, it went from row 39 to 40 without any repetitions.

Comment: @Plutonix I update my post with the codes for `for each cell` loop based on your suggestion, but the header row and the 1st row now seems to overlap each other. Am I placing the codes right?

Comment: You need **two** for loops - a new "special"  one to print the headers when `newpage` is true, then the one to print values

Comment: @Plutonix Is it a for loop within a for loop?

Comment: Very usefull. How to change paper orientation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24656705/1070452) is a nice start  but has a couple of bugs and inefficiecies:

- It uses the `newpage` flag to print the header **or** the first row when there is a new page.  Obviously you really want it to do both
- Printing the column headers is done once per page, so it doesnt need to be in the data print loop at all
- It is not allowing for invisible columns or columns with other than default alignment,  There could be other such settings you want to account for.
- Because it is not actually printing the correct number of rows, once you fix that you'll find that it reprints the last row from the previous page as the first row of a new page.
- There is an internal gutter or margin so that text does not print too close to gridlines - this just uses an offset of 1 or 2
- It is also needlessly using `single` and `RectangleF`
- It is also not prepared for the Document to be shown again or Printed. You will also want to reset `mRow` and `newpage` either in the button click or `BeginPrint` event.

I added a few comments as well as coloring the header row and demonstrating how to implement things like a `RowPrePaint` rule.

```
Private mRow As Integer = 0
Private newpage As Boolean = True

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object,
                    e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    ' sets it to show '...' for long text
    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
    Dim y As Int32 = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim rc As Rectangle
    Dim x As Int32
    Dim h As Int32 = 0
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow

    ' print the header text for a new page
    '   use a grey bg just like the control
    If newpage Then
        row = dgvZZ.Rows(mRow)
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            ' since we are printing the control's view,
            ' skip invidible columns
            If cell.Visible Then
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rc)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                ' reused in the data pront - should be a function
                Select Case dgvZZ.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight,
                         DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                        rc.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                        DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    Case Else
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                        rc.Offset(2, 0)
                End Select

                e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvZZ.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText,
                                            dgvZZ.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            End If
        Next
        y += h

    End If
    newpage = False

    ' now print the data for each row
    Dim thisNDX As Int32
    For thisNDX = mRow To dgvZZ.RowCount - 1
        ' no need to try to print the new row
        If dgvZZ.Rows(thisNDX).IsNewRow Then Exit For

        row = dgvZZ.Rows(thisNDX)
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left
        h = 0

        ' reset X for data
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left

        ' print the data
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If cell.Visible Then
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

                ' SAMPLE CODE: How To 
                ' up a RowPrePaint rule
                'If Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells(5).Value) < 9.99 Then
                '    Using br As New SolidBrush(Color.MistyRose)
                '        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rc)
                '    End Using
                'End If

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                Select Case dgvZZ.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight,
                         DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                        rc.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                        DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    Case Else
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                        rc.Offset(2, 0)
                End Select

                e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.FormattedValue.ToString(),
                                      dgvZZ.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)

                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            End If

        Next
        y += h
        ' next row to print
        mRow = thisNDX + 1

        If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
            e.HasMorePages = True
            ' mRow -= 1   causes last row to rePrint on next page
            newpage = True
            Return
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

[image][image]

Note that there is an `Id` column set to invisible in the DGV, the `Color` column is centered and `Price` is left justified - these are all settings picked up from the control. Also note that the text is moved away from the gridlines just a bit.

---

The last bullet point above, *You will also want to reset `mRow` and `newpage` either in the button click or `BeginPrint` event.* means this:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(sender As Object, 
          e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
    mRow = 0
    newpage = True
    PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.StartPage = 0
    PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1.0
End Sub
```

After you preview the `mRow` variable will indicate that all the rows have been printed.  If the user clicks Print or goes back for another Preview, nothing will print.  This code also resets the first page to show and the initial Zoom.