# DGV Header disappears when I close print preview dialog

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a print preview dialog control in a system and I want it to print a DGV table that I have in my application. I'm able to print the table without any problems, but there is a very curious problem.

After I run the application and open the print preview control, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOmoz.png). I realize after closing the print preview dialog and reopening it after meddling around in the system, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJKcO.png) is what I get. Does anyone know why this is happening?

These are the codes I'm using.

```
    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
    Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim rc As Rectangle
    Dim x As Int32
    Dim h As Int32 = 0

    Do While mRow < dgvChemical.RowCount
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dgvChemical.Rows(mRow)
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left
        h = 0

        If newPage Then
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rc)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvChemical.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, dgvChemical.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            y += h
            mRow += 0
        End If
        newPage = False

        x = e.MarginBounds.Left

        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.FormattedValue.ToString(), dgvChemical.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)

            x += rc.Width
            h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
        Next

        y += h
        mRow += 1
        If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
            e.HasMorePages = True
            newPage = True
            Return
        End If
    Loop

    mRow = 0

    Dim ps As PaperSize
    For ix As Integer = 0 To PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1
        If PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(ix).Kind = PaperKind.A3 Then
            ps = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(ix)
            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps
            PageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.PaperSize = ps
        End If
    Next`
```

Comment: Could be `newPage` not being reset. Where is this declared? You may want to look at setting this back to `True` when you come to print preview again. What calls this bit of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer to your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41022394/1070452) includes a bullet point to *be sure `mRow` and `newpage` are reset* in the button click which starts the printing.  Otherwise those form/class level variables will start with whatever value they were from the last session.

You might also want to reset the start page. If the user left it with page 17 showing, it will also start on that page the next time. That may or may not be desirable.

```
Private Sub printDGV_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles printDGV.Click
    ' need to start fresh eash time
    mRow = 0
    newpage = True

    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    ' optionally reset the first page shown
    PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.StartPage = 0
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```