# Print Preview DataGridview skips a row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Im having my project here which is my button in Print Preview should get all the content from my datagridview but the problem is the first row in my datagridview content is not displaying always in my Print Preview. How could I fix this? by the way I get this code to others, Credits to him. I think it skipping the first row. In Datagridview [image] 
Then in Print Preview [image]

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        Dim mRow As Integer = 0
        Dim newpage As Boolean = True

        With DataGridView1
            Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
            fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
            Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
            Do While mRow < .RowCount
                Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
                Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
                Dim h As Single = 0
                For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                    Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                    If (newpage) Then
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                    Else
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                    End If
                    x += rc.Width
                    h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
                Next
                newpage = False
                y += h
                mRow += 1
                If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                    mRow -= 1
                    newpage = True

                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Loop
            mRow = 0

        End With

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There are a number of issues with the code you found.  Someone else had the same issue(s)

Comment: By the way, you should document where your code comes from so you can go back and check things.  For here, with this type of question you should link to the source (not just "him") so we can check if you copied correctly.  And, if you are using his code, you ought to take a micro-second and upvote the post.

Comment: The layout is wrong. The `mRow` variable should be class level. The loop should be `For row As Integer = mRow To .RowCount - 1`. When you detect the end of the page you simple exit the sub and the `mRow` variable kept track of it's position in the loop then continues from there when the event fires again. `mRow` would be set to 0 from the event that starts the print/preview process.

Comment: Yes, those are new issues this OP introduced.  The MAIN problem is that when there is a new page, it is not a matter of printing the header **OR** the next row, you want to do both (which means that `IF (newpage)` check doesnt need to be in the loop at all).

Comment: THank YOu @Plutonix got solve my issue with that post. I didnt know that the other guys has the same issue with me. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if it helped by all means upvote [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41022394/1070452) - that is, click the Up Arrow next to it. I should think on the average day you'd burn 5-10 votes per visit @KenthJoshuaEspina