# Exporting DataGridView to PDF Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, datagridview

I'm having a problem here regarding code I saw posted here: [How to print datagridview table with its header in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015287/how-to-print-datagridview-table-with-its-header-in-vb-net/41434597?noredirect=1#comment70217285_41434597)

I'm testing without a printer and just saving it as a .pdf file, but it doesn't export the `DataGridView`. Can anyone help me? What could be the problem?

As you can see, it is visible in Print Preview:

[image]

After I save as pdf (because I don't have printer available to test with): [image]

My code:

```
 Private mRow As Integer = 0
    Private newpage As Boolean = True
    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(12, 9, CInt(PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width), lblCurriculumName.Height)
    Dim sf As New StringFormat
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lblCurriculumName.Text, lblCurriculumName.Font, Brushes.Black, rect, sf)
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

    Dim rect1 As New Rectangle(97, 60, CInt(PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width), txtFullName.Height)
    Dim sf1 As New StringFormat
    sf1.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
    sf1.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
    e.Graphics.DrawString(txtFullName.Text, txtFullName.Font, Brushes.Black, rect1, sf1)
    sf1.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

    ' sets it to show '...' for long text
    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
    Dim y As Int32 = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim rc As Rectangle
    Dim x As Int32
    Dim h As Int32 = 0
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow

    ' print the header text for a new page
    '   use a grey bg just like the control
    If newpage Then
        row = DataGridView1.Rows(mRow)
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            ' since we are printing the control's view,
            ' skip invidible columns
            If cell.Visible Then
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rc)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                ' reused in the data pront - should be a function
                Select Case DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight,
                         DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                        rc.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                        DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    Case Else
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                        rc.Offset(2, 0)
                End Select

                e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText,
                                           DataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            End If
        Next
        y += h

    End If
    newpage = False

    ' now print the data for each row
    Dim thisNDX As Int32
    For thisNDX = mRow To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        ' no need to try to print the new row
        If DataGridView1.Rows(thisNDX).IsNewRow Then Exit For

        row = DataGridView1.Rows(thisNDX)
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left
        h = 0

        ' reset X for data
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left

        ' print the data
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If cell.Visible Then
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

                ' pick up any RowPrePaint rule
                If Convert.ToString(row.Cells(2).Value.ToString) = "NG" Then
                    Using br As New SolidBrush(Color.MistyRose)
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rc)
                    End Using
                End If

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                Select Case DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight,
                         DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                        rc.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                        DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    Case Else
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                        rc.Offset(2, 0)
                End Select

                e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.FormattedValue.ToString(),
                                     DataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)

                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            End If


        Next
        y += h
        ' next row to print
        mRow = thisNDX + 1

        If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
            e.HasMorePages = True
            mRow -= 1   'causes last row to rePrint on next page
            newpage = True
            Return
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

    'need to start fresh each time
    mRow = 0
    newpage = True

    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    'optionally reset the first page shown
    PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.StartPage = 0
    PrintPreviewDialog1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the document has printed as a Preview, if you decide to print, the document has to be printed again.  This means all that code in `PrintDocument1_PrintPage` has to run again, this time sending the output to the printer.

However, at the end of the Preview, `mRow` will be the max number of DGV rows and `newpage` is false so it appears there is nothing to print.  The solution is to initialize those in the `BeginPrint` event:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(sender As Object, 
               e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
    mRow = 0
    newpage = True
    PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.StartPage = 0
    PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1.0
End Sub
```

Now, when printing starts again for the printer, they are set to process the entire document.  The code also resets the first page to show and the initial Zoom.

Comment: Wow @Plutonix the code really works now and I understand. You really help me a lot in my thesis,, hehe.. I should acknowledge you. Thank You Sir.