# How to print DataGridView's selected rows to Printdocument in VB

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview

I'm trying to print all selected rows from a Datagridview on Form1 to a Printdocument on Form2.

```
    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Dim fon As New Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12, FontStyle.Regular)

    e.Graphics.DrawString(Detalle_Editar.CODIGO.HeaderText, fon, Brushes.Black, 300, 200)

    Dim ce = Detalle_Editar.Detalle_VDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex

    e.Graphics.DrawString(Detalle_Editar.Detalle_VDataGridView.Item(Detalle_Editar.CODIGO.HeaderText, ce).Value.ToString, fon, Brushes.Black, 300, 200)

End Sub
```

When i run the code I get "objet reference not set to an instance of an object" on this line:

```
Dim ce = Detalle_Editar.Detalle_VDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex
```

Do you have a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: CurrentCell / CurrentRow has no role in printing the DGV.  If you want to print just some of the rows, iterate the SelectedRows collection.  There's lots of stuff missing in your print method.  [How to print datagridview table with its header in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41015287/1070452)

Comment: Im new at this. Thanks for the link. Im working on it.

Comment: Since you *are* new, you should read [ask] and take the [tour].